# Is there a way to easily get the JavaScript representation of a C# model?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I declare a few C# models for my data. However, I also  process the data on client side and it would be nice if I could somehow get a JavaScript representation of a C# class so I do not have to re-declare the same data structures in JavaScript. Ideally, in my client code I would reference a script with class name as a query string parameter and it would return the JS code defining the constructor for the needed C# class. E.g.

```
<script src="/model/get?type=Myapp.User"></script>
```

Of course, it would all happen in runtime with help of reflection.

Is there any existing solution that does that? Thank you.

Comment: Basically, this isn't possible.  There are so many services, language constructs, and incompatibilities between your application and what JS and the browser can offer you.

Answer (score 0):

You can return instances of objects as JSON using built in [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) class, but for type information you will need to build something yourself (again likely returning as JSON).

Answer (score 0):

```
Json.Encode(MyObject)
```

or get newtonsofts json library (its better),  It has many options, including type information,  which can be useful for inheritance.

However.... any circular references are problems.  Quite often its better to make an anonymous object with a minimal object structure that your view needs, then encode that.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Will this approach create a JavaScript object constructor for me? I am going to create objects in JavaScript myself, I don't need existing objects coded in Json.

Comment: it just gives you json, however, that is extremely useful....  you can then use that to initialise your own object, or do whatever.   As an example, in knockout js, you simply call a method to map the json onto an object and it converts all the json into observables onto a target object.